# how to generate next ID from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms, linq

I am using a service-based database (`*.mdf`) as my database service. I'm using Linq-To-SQL classes.

I want to generate the next ID. Currently I'm trying to get the ID of the last inserted row, then add 1 to get the next ID. My primary key's data type is int.

```
private string genNextId()
{
    var id = (from a in dc.nasabahs
              orderby a.nomor_nasabah ascending
              select a.nomor_nasabah).Last();

    return id.ToString();
}
```

I get the error:

> The query operator 'Last' is not supported.

Comment: Why not order by descending, then do first?

Comment: idk why, lol and it works ! btw, what's wrong with `last()` ?

Comment: Honestly, I couldn't tell you, I was just taking a shot in the dark :)

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1268557.aspx/1  Looks like it's the same conversation, linq to sql doesn't seem to support .last

Comment: First, why do you need to get the next id?  Why not use an identity column that auto-generates the id?  The whole point of an ORM is that you shouldn't need to worry about this in most situations, as the ORM will take care of inserting the generated id in any linked tables.  The reason I ask "why do you need to do this?" is because more often than not when people ask these questions, it's because they are doing something the wrong way.. and rather than ask about the right way to do it, they instead focus their question on why the wrong way is failing.  This is known as the XY Problem.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @MystereMan: It certainly smells so.

Comment: You should ***NOT*** try to generate the next ID yourself. The `MAX()+1` approach is flawed - it will very quickly break under load (with multiple concurrent clients) and will produce duplicate values. Don't do this - use what is present in SQL Server to properly handle this: an `IDENTITY` column. That's the best and only reliable way to handle unique ID stories - do try to reinvent the wheel !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a slightly different approach?

```
private string genNextId()
{
    var id = (from a in dc.nasabahs
              select a.nomor_nasabah).Max();

    return id.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Not sure which is more efficient run-time wise between our answers, but I do like this one, just a different approach

Comment: Yeah, it would require some execution plan investigation. Ideally, the database is designed such that an `order by` wouldn't bring it to its knees, but you never know. Also, I just wanted to provide options.

Answer (score 2):

Change your funciton to this:

```
private string genNextId()
    {
        var id = (from a in dc.nasabahs
                  orderby a.nomor_nasabah descending
                  select a.nomor_nasabah).First();

        return id.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this you should use a sequence which is available only in SQL Server 2012 although other databases like Oracle has it for ages. [Sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) is a database object that generates numeric value and once a value is generated and consumed it will not be re-generated. The advantage is that you can get a value without doing any insert. However I don't think linq-to-sql supports this so you will have to use raw ado.net.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought about adding my two cents. Everyone above didn't really tell how to configure identity property for service-based database or mdx file.
After you create table or during first time creation, go to table definition and then in column properties you will see something like Identity Specification:
Is Identity, mark as Yes.Increment set as 1 ( depending upon your desired step size) and Seed set as 1 (Initial value)